# apexcharts basic timeline with decimal numbers

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am using basic timeline chart of Apexcharts in React application, where the data contains decimal numbers (e.g: data = [{"x":"TaskData0link_Node0_Node1","y":[0.0,0.05]}].
However when I enter the bars with the mouse I can only see values that are rounded . In this case: 0-0.
Is it somehow possible to display the real values (0-0.05)? And not round it to integer.

The options that I use:

```
options: {
            chart: {
                height: 350,
                type: 'rangeBar',
                toolbar: {
                    show: true,
                    autoSelected: 'selection'
                },
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    horizontal: true
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                type: 'numeric',
                title: {
                    text: 'in ms'
                },
                labels: {
                    show: true
                },
                decimalInFloat: 3,

            },
        },
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this custom tooltip

```
tooltip: {
  custom: ({ dataPointIndex, w }) => {
    let s = w.config.series[0].data[dataPointIndex];
    return `<div class="apexcharts-tooltip-rangebar"><div>
  <span class="category">${s.x}: </span>
  <span class="value start-value">${s.y[0]}</span>
  <span class="separator">-</span>
  <span class="value end-value">${s.y[1]}</span></div></div>`;
  }
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. One more question. Is it maybe also possible to round it to e.g two decimals after the comma?

Comment: Replace `s.y[0]` and `s.y[1]` with `parseFloat(s.y[0].toFixed(2))` for two decimals. Without `parseFloat` you will always get two decimals after comma (5.1.toFixed(2) = 5.10).

Answer (score 0):

//There are two ways for its solution :-

```
`1) options.yaxis: {
labels: {
  formatter: function(value) {
    return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
  }

},
tickAmount: 5,
min: 0,
max: 'Your Y axis maximum value here like 5000',
}

2) options.yaxis: {
  tickAmount: 5,
  `enter code here`
  min: 0,
  max: 'Your Y axis maximum value here like 5000',
  decimalsInFloat: 2
}`
```

[Value shows on Y axis using Apex Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4KJR.png)

Comment: So here we can see that we can use in yaxis: {
            labels: { formatter: function (value) {
                    return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
                }
            },
            tickAmount: 5,
            min: 0,
            max: 5000,
        }, or instead labels we can use decimalsInFloat: 2